ubuntu linux (WSL) alternative starting directory shortcut?
this is a newbie question so feel free to simply point me to resources but:
how can I somehow configure an alternative starting directory? I'm using WSL (because why would i want to use windows powershell lol) and my default starting directory looks like this:
/home/il_velan

but because i started using WSL a short while after i've had some project already set up in a different location, where i have files that i'd been working with through file explorer that i want to access sometimes, some of my projects are stored under:
/mnt/c/Users/il_velan

so my question is: how do i create a simple way of using the latter directory with having to do
cd ../../mnt/c/Users/il_velan

every time? I know this doesn't seem that big a deal but it really bugs me that I have to do it manually ALL THE TIME
alternatively, do you think i should bite the bullet and migrate everything to /home/il_velan? are all of your projects supposed to be under the same directory? what is the best practice for those who are professionals? what else am i not considering?

I went ahead and closed this as a duplicate based on two things (1) The main part of the question isn't necessarily about programming, so it's off-topic here. And then in the last sentence you ask about the "best practices" here, and I think you'll find the answer to that in the linked duplicate.

Also see my Super User answer here for how to change the default. It looks like you are using ubuntu.exe (or the Start menu equivalent) to launch here, which pretty much always launches to your Linux home directory.  It's possible change this, as mentioned in that post, using the wsl --cd <directory> argument.  That can be set as part of the profile in Windows Terminal (or whatever terminal you use).
